# How do I stop TCP reset packets?

Tags: networking, security, tcp, wireshark, tcpip

**Full story**: This has been quite the odyssee, finding out who is sending these TCP reset packets. The isp pointed me in the direction of the minecraft server, the minecraft server said it has to be the isp or upstream isp and those guys probably have bigger problems than one little guy with connection problems. Then I realized I might have been asking the wrong question. Who cares who is sending them and why? Let's ask the server hardware directly if it is sending them and otherwise let's ignore those fun-stoppers all together and continue the connection anyways. The server is still sending normal packest after the reset, so why not normally answer those as if I didn't hear about the reset? The sequence numbers are fishy as heck anyways. I mean, why is there a second package numbered 9068 when we are already at number 9372?

**Idea**: I found [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7203961B1/en) on how to prevent TCP reset attacks and [some random website](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junose15.1/topics/task/configuration/tcp-rst-syn-dos-attack-protection.html) mentioning a "tcp ack-rst-and-syn" config, but it is not mentioned where and how to apply that.

[image: TCP ACK-RST-SYN]

This seems to be exactly the thing that might help me with the following situation:

TCP Dump (Visualized)

[image: TCP Dump]

TCP Dump (Wireshark)

```
No.    Time         Protocol  TTL    Info
146    22:17:15,725    TCP    128    63626 → 25565 [ACK]      Seq=187  Ack=9068 Win=1023 Len=0
147    22:17:15,738    TCP    128    63626 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=187  Ack=9068 Win=1023 Len=7
148    22:17:15,738    TCP    128    63626 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=194  Ack=9068 Win=1023 Len=7
150    22:17:15,739    TCP    128    63626 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=201  Ack=9068 Win=1023 Len=4
151    22:17:15,767    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9068 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=21
152    22:17:15,767    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9089 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=7
153    22:17:15,767    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9096 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=10
154    22:17:15,767    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9106 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=10
155    22:17:15,767    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9116 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=256
156    22:17:15,767    TCP    128    63626 → 25565 [ACK]      Seq=205  Ack=9372 Win=1022 Len=0
160    22:17:15,780    TCP    51     25565 → 63626 [RST]      Seq=9068          Win=0    Len=0
161    22:17:15,782    TCP    128    63626 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=205  Ack=9372 Win=1022 Len=7
162    22:17:15,784    TCP    128    63626 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=212  Ack=9372 Win=1022 Len=4
163    22:17:15,785    TCP    51     25565 → 63626 [RST]      Seq=9068          Win=0    Len=0
164    22:17:15,785    TCP    51     25565 → 63626 [RST]      Seq=9068          Win=0    Len=0
166    22:17:15,805    TCP    51     25565 → 63626 [RST]      Seq=9372          Win=0    Len=0
171    22:17:15,813    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9372 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=7
172    22:17:15,828    TCP    51     25565 → 63626 [RST]      Seq=9372          Win=0    Len=0
173    22:17:15,828    TCP    51     25565 → 63626 [RST]      Seq=9372          Win=0    Len=0
174    22:17:15,832    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9379 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=21
176    22:17:15,834    TCP    49     25565 → 63626 [PSH, ACK] Seq=9400 Ack=187  Win=68   Len=27
```

**Question**: My question now is how and where do I implement the described TCP RST attack countermeasure, which asks for approval before blindly closing a connection? (or something like it if that's not possible)

In case you need my hardware and software specifications for that, it is a Windows 10 machine hooked up to a FRITZ!Box 4040.

Comment: With a quick cursory look, it sounds like that's a Cisco thing so you get that network which is receiving those on a Cisco device that supports that I suppose. You then see if you can figure out how to turn that functionality on or ask Cisco if it needs to be turned on or if it's on by default on the correlated device.

Comment: Yes, that was part of my question: How do I acheive something like this without a Cisco device.

Comment: If there is a patent that Cisco owns, then wouldn't that infringe on that patent? If that's the case, it may not be legal but these are just quick thoughts with quick reading on the topic. Once I saw it was Cisco and there was a patent, I suggested getting the hardware that support that Cisco proprietary and patented protocol.

Comment: May be it would be easier to simply use a VPN and test if you can tunnel the problematic network.

Comment: You can, but the server I connect to bans you for using a VPN, so I better not do that...